Ruby on Rails App with nginx, passenger, and ruby installed via asdf globally
I'm trying to use phusion passenger with rails (an old version of ruby/rails, but I'm in the process of upgrading... this is the first step). Anyway, I installed ruby 2.6.1 with asdf, which is installed to /opt/asdf on my EC2 instance, and it's working with both root and deployer-bot (my deployment user). However, where it doesn't work is with the nginx configuration.
My nginx configuration for the site in question is as follows:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/current/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /opt/asdf/shims/ruby;
    passenger_sticky_sessions on;
    passenger_app_env staging;
}

When I try to access that site, I get the following error in the logs:
output: unknown command: ruby. Perhaps you have to reshim?

My guess is this is related to the fact that www-data (the user that the nginx server is running as) does not have the correct sourcing for the asdf.sh script. If I create a new user, say, someuser, login to that user, and attempt to run /opt/asdf/shims/ruby, I get the same error:
unknown command: ruby. Perhaps you have to reshim?

I'm not quite sure what to do here, though. www-data doesn't really have a home directory (it's home is set to /var/www), nor does it have a login shell. Is there some way I can get asdf's environment set up when passenger is starting?

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html
